# Makefile to support 2 executables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to update my Makefile to support building a binary of my project, and a binary of some Unit Tests.

My directory structure is the following

```
|-code/
|--|--src/
|--|--inc/
|
|-tests/
|--|--src/
|--|--inc/
```

My makefile compiles the binary from code well, but is having some issues with the test. The test folder contains some unit test that tests some classes in code/src/. I have a file main.cpp in code/src/ that contains the main() function, and also another file, called test.cpp in tests/src that contains its own main() function.

This led me to this complicated Makefile:

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -g -c -Wall

INCLUDEDIR = -Icode/inc -Itests/inc
BUILDDIR = build

SOURCEDIR = code/src
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(SOURCEDIR)))
TEMP_OBJ = $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
NOT_DIR = $(notdir $(TEMP_OBJ))
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(NOT_DIR))

TEST_DIR = tests/src
TEST_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(TEST_DIR)))
TEST_TEMP_OBJ = $(TEST_SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
TEST_NOT_DIR = $(notdir $(TEST_TEMP_OBJ))
TEST_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(TEST_NOT_DIR))

EXECUTABLE = Client
TEST_EXECUTABLE = TestUnit

all: $(BUILDDIR) $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE) $(BUILDDIR)/$(TEST_EXECUTABLE)

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : code/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    @rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/main.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : tests/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
```

It fails with the error:

```
g++: error: build/main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/TestUnit] Error 1
```

Which is because I have the line:

```
@rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/main.o
```

but otherwise I would get the error (there is main in main.cpp and test.cpp in code/src/ and tests/code/ respectively):

```
/tests/src/test.cpp:7: multiple definition of `main'
code/src/main.cpp:6: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is a lot of duplication in my Makefile, and I would love to get something more succinct that achieves the purpose of building 2 binaries from those 2 folders, although code is shared.

Any help would please be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: I presume that `code/src/main.cpp` has a `main()`. What is the name of the source file in `tests/src/` that also has a `main()`?

Comment: You are right, main.cpp has a main(). It is test.cpp in tests/src/ that has the other main(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this makefile.

First, there is no rule to build test object files, such as `test.o`. The only rule for building objects requires that the source be in `code/src/`; I don't know how you even get far enough to see a linker error.

Let's change the object rule to a static pattern rule:

```
$(OBJECTS) : $(BUILDDIR)/%.o : code/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@
```

Then we can add an additional rule for the test objects:

```
$(TEST_OBJECTS) : $(BUILDDIR)/%.o : tests/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@
```

(Never mind the redundancy for now-- we have to get it working first.)

*Now* we should see a linker error in this rule:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    ...
```

In that list of prerequisites are two files, `main.o` and `test.o` fighting over who gets to define `main()`. We want `test.o`, so `main.o` must go:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(filter-out build/main.o,$(OBJECTS)) $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    ...
```

Try this much and tell us the result. Once it's working we can slim it down.

Comment: Answering your first comment: There is a rule for TEST_DIR = tests/src, that gets set as TEST_OBJECTS (for like test.o). The rule: $(BUILDDIR)/$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(TEST_OBJECTS) creates TEST_OBJECTS, which uses $(BUILDDIR)/%.o : tests/src/%.cpp. I am going to give a shot at your solution, will report soon. thanks!

Comment: @Jary: sorry, I missed that. I'll correct my answer once we have the conflict fixed.

Comment: No problem! It's a big Makefile with full of duplicate entries from my part, it's my mistake :)

Comment: Good news!! This line did the trick: $(BUILDDIR)/$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(filter-out build/main.o,$(OBJECTS)) $(TEST_OBJECTS).   I gave the shot at the static pattern just to give it a shot, but it ended up exactly the same. Thanks a lot! :) I should re-write it to avoid all this duplicate code.